# Android Browser .Net framework 2.0 is not installed or ActiveX is not supported

Tags: android

I was browsing a web site on my company and tried to launch a chart from a web page through default browser of Android phone (Google Nexus). But when I click the button to launch the chart it gave me this error  *.Net framework 2.0 is not installed or ActiveX is not supported*.

On desktop the same website shows the chart in a new window.

I guess that the chart window might be linking to some .net library which is not present on 
the device.

Any other idea why this is happening, or any way to make is run on my device.

Regards,
Yasir

Answer (score 1):

ActiveX is only supported on IE even on desktops and not supported at all on Android.

The only "way" would be to remotely connect to your Windows box via a RDP client for Android and try to use it that way.